# When building an optical system, how can I increase the size of the useful image?

Tags: optics, lenses, imaging

I am trying to put together a system of lenses that has a probe with a 2 mm diameter. The system has a probe with an objective and a relay and a set of lenses with a larger diameter that function as a microscope, magnifying the image generated by the objective. The attached Figure 1 gives a rough description of the system. The problem is that the generated useful image is too small, as seen in Figure 2. I thought that this problem would be solved by selecting appropriate field lenses that would image the exit pupil of the previous lenses set onto the entrance pupil of the next, but it seems it is not working. What can be done to increase the size of the useful image? Ideally, the size of the useful image should be as marked with a red circle in Figure 3.

[image: Figure 1. A rough description of the system]

[image: Figure 2. The current useful image]

[image: Figure 3. Desired useful image size]

Comment: I like the question. I would have made the same assumption about entrance and exit pupils. I can't see what is wrong with it... I hope somebody who knows more about the subtleties of optics can see the problem and explain to us where our mistake is, if there is a mistake. Did you check the beam sizes for a bright light source the size of your expected object area experimentally by inserting a screen in the beam path? That should be a quick diagnostic to check where the limiting aperture occurs.

Comment: Can you say more about the way you tried to solve the problem? In theory a 4f system should solve the problem. Have you tried that?

Comment: @FlatterMann I tried this previously and the light beam appears to be converging and diverging as expected throughout the system.

Comment: @flippiefanus The magnification of the objective was defined to make the scaled image of the field of view smaller than the probe lenses (2 mm diameter lenses). The relay is basically a 4F system where the two lenses have the same focal length. The next stage, which functions as a microscope, magnifies the image. The magnification of the first microscope stage is 2x. The eyepiece is designed to collimate the output beam and locate the system's exit pupil at 5 mm away from the last lens (considering the last lens as the lens near the eye).  The exit pupil size is 1 mm in diameter.

Answer (score 1):

I asked in the Zemax forum and they suggested that the problem was the magnification. And that was it! Magnification was the cause of the problem. I thought by matching the pupils and ensuring an appropriate size for the exit pupil I would have a good image size but that was not the case. To find the best image size I played with the magnifications of the two stages of the system as shown in the system layout image attached. I picked an angular magnification for stage 2 of 0.1111 and a paraxial magnification of -5 for stage 1. When I tried to increase the magnifications above, the stages' performance decreased too much. I also attached an image captured with the new configuration.

[image: System layout]

[image: Example image]

Thank you for the comments.